# How to enable asp.net-mvc6 to return JSONP instead of JSON

Tags: jquery, web-services, jsonp, asp.net-core-mvc

I've just started with the new asp.net-mvc6 and run into some problems.
The documentation is still not very helpfull and I hope some of you guys can help me.

I've build a small website with one single page and I use one Controller as webservice to feed an autocomplete textfield with jquery.

As it is on the same domain, everything works fine.

Now I want to reuse the webservice inside of a wordpress blog which is hosted on a different server.
I reused my jQuery code from some older projects to get an JSONP response from my webservice but it doesn't work.

It seems, that it doesn't generate the right callback function on the server and always only returns plain JSON.

Is there any point in some config file or something else, where I can tell my server to return JSONP instead of JSON?

Or do you have a working example code for an asp.net-mvc6 project with JSONP?

Big Thanks and regards
Gogglehead

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using JSONP, you may want to consider Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) which is now supported by all major browsers: [Can I Use Listing](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors)

This option is great because it allows the use of standard JSON and only requires an additional response header to work.  If you have a project that contains only web services that you don't mind being shared, you can enable it for the whole project via the web.config file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <!-- Enable Cross-Origin Requests -->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you only want this enabled for a specific controller action, that can be accomplished as well by modifying the headers collection:

```
    [HttpGet("{subject}/{number}")]
    public CourseList Get(string subject, int number)
    {
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new string[] { "*" });
        CourseList list = new CourseList();
        //Retrieve the data
        return list;
    }
```